# The intuitive proof of $[\Sigma X, K] = [X,\Omega K]$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to know the proof of $[\Sigma X, K] = [X,\Omega K]$ which is called "adjoint relation "

Here $\Sigma X = SX/\{x_0\}\times I$, and $\Omega K$ is a space of loops in $K$ at chosen base point.

And $[Y,Z]$ is a set of homotopy classes of a map $Y\to Z$.

Thanks in advance.

[Refer]

Same question is already discussed :

[What is the easiest way to see $\langle \Sigma X, Y \rangle\cong \langle X,\Omega Y\rangle $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201477/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-see-langle-sigma-x-y-rangle-cong-langle-x-omeg?rq=1)

But this article provides a rough idea, or hom tensor adjunction argument, which 
is algebraic.

[Partial Explanation]

By definition of $[\Sigma X, K]$, we have $[\Sigma X, K] \subset [X,\Omega K]$ and 
 for $f\in [\Sigma X, K]$, $f$ gives $f \in [X,\Omega K] $ such that $f(x_0)$ is a constant loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof is provided in my answer:

[Loop space suspension/adjunction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443259/loop-space-suspension-adjunction/443381#443381)

I'm not sure I follow your partial explanation: the homotopy class of the map $f\in [X,\Omega K]$ sending all $x\in X$ to the constant loop at the basepoint of $K$ corresponds to the homotopy class of the constant map in $[\Sigma X,K]$ under the loop space/suspension adjunction. The restriction of a map $\Sigma X\to K$ to $X$ doesn't even define a map $X\to \Omega K$. (Why?) So, we don't have an inclusion $[\Sigma X,K]\subseteq [X,\Omega K]$ as you describe.

I hope this helps!